# Should I stop and recreate the thread or should I use wait() and notify() to deal with a game-loop, in Android?

Tags: android, android-activity, onresume, onpause, game-loop

how should I deal with the game loop when the user switches from my Android game to something else and then back?

1. Stopping and recreating the thread
2. Pausing/continuing the thread using wait() and notify()

**Option #1** would look like this:

```
public void run() {
    while (isRunning) {
        // do stuff
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    boolean retry = true;
    gameLoop.setRunning(false);

    while (retry) {
        try {
            mainThread.join();
            retry = false;
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    if (gameLoop.isRunning()) {
        stop();
    }

    gameLoop.setRunning(true);

    mainThread = new Thread(gameLoop);
    mainThread.start();

    super.onResume();
}
```

**Option #2** would look like this:

```
public void run() {
    while (!mFinished) {
        // do stuff
        
        synchronized (mPauseLock) {
            while (mPaused) {
                try {
                    mPauseLock.wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    synchronized (mPauseLock) {
        mPaused = true;
    }

    super.onPause();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    synchronized (mPauseLock) {
        mPaused = false;
        mPauseLock.notifyAll();
    }

    super.onResume();
}
```

Which option is the better one? And also **should I use onPause()/onResume() or onStop()/onStart() to do these thread operations?**

Thank you!